# Do I need separate files for each test with ctest?

Tags: c++, cmake, ctest

There is a lot I don't understand when it comes to cmake and ctest. I actually can't find a good tutorial or something that explains ctest well.

I tried to write a few tests for my code. I put the tests in different functions that are all called from a main.cpp like this:

```
int main()
{
    test1();
    test2();
    test3();
    ...
    exit(0);
}
```

I've created a CMakeLists.txt to create a target *tests*.

```
set (TESTS
        main.cpp
)
add_executable (tests ${TESTS})
target_link_libraries (tests ...)

enable_testing()
add_test(my-test tests)
```

Now I can call **ctest run**

```
$ ctest run
Test project /.../tests
    Start 1: my-test
1/1 Test #1: my-test .........................   Passed    0.01 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.01 sec
```

But this gives me only one test case although internally I have multiple test cases, each in a separate function. I could extract the functions to separate files, but this way I'd have hundreds of files. How can I avoid having separate files for each test?

I was looking for something like this.

```
add_test( test1 tests::test1() )
add_test( test2 tests::test2() )
```

I'm fully aware that this is wrong and naive and so on. But I hope you'll get an idea of my problem.

Answer (score 5):

CTest only works with commands, i.e. executables or equivalent. It invokes test runners. It is not a test runner itself.

The normal approach to testing is

1. to use a testing framework which supports granular testing and result output to create test runners, e.g. Catch or Google Test/Google Mock or Python
2. to group test runners by category, e.g. unit testing or integration, and preferably within each category organize by time
3. to group unit tests within each test runner by module, i.e. a unit test runner never tests more than one module.

So, from that perspective, your problem appears to be step 1: you need a testing framework to create granular test output.

Comment: I've been using cmocka, with good results.  But that's for C-only

Answer (score 1):

CMake can generate a test_runner executable. See the blog entry of Noel O'Boyle for a description how to create multiple tests in a single file: https://baoilleach.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-ctest-with-multiple-tests-in.html?m=1